# java.io.FileNotFoundException: It is not able to locate my file?

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I am trying to implement a text file and a Bufferedreader in my Android Studio project but it is saying that the file cannot be found. 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oldby.png). Help?

Comment: It says "unhandled exception". https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Comment: Can you please edit your question include the relevant code and error as text?

Comment: Have you created a file in that location i.e. where you're working directory ??? and check the permission of file too. Give the file path if your file is located in some other directory

Comment: You might have solved your problem by now. Here is a bit of suggestion : Whenever you get problematic line of code in `Android Studio`, just click on the underlined code and press `Alt + Enter` (`Ctl + 1` in `Eclipse`). The IDE will give you the most common solutions and by clicking any of them it will get managed by itself(if there are possible solutions).

Comment: And it is not like "It is not able to find the file". You can never know that without running the code. The editor is just telling you that this piece of code can throw the particular exception and can crash the app if you don't handle it with `try-catch` block.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The exception appears when a file cannot be created, or the file exists but its permissions are insufficient for changing its content.

Doing try/catch might work.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio says that there is a possibility of **FileNotFoundException**. So, you have to surround the error statement with try and catch block.

```
try {
    BufferedReader latQ = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("LatinQuotes.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working... It now says that the 'try' and 'catch' are unexpected tokens.

Comment: Copy the whole try and catch block and put it in **onCeate(Bundle SavedInstance)** method. Try and catch block should always be inside a method. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to surround the FileReader constructor with a try...catch block for FileNotFoundException. The reason for this is that the FileReader constructor you are using throws a checked exception. What that means is that the constructor's method signature declares that it "throws FileNotFoundException". This means that anyone that uses the constructor needs to "check" for that exception, or catch it. You should look into the concept of checked exceptions in Java.